# How can I remove multiple tab bar items in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

```
    NSMutableArray *copyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
    [self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
    [copyArray removeObjectAtIndex:3];
    [copyArray removeObjectAtIndex:4];
    [copyArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [copyArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:copyArray animated:false];
```

This one is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue you need to remove object in *descending* order of arrya index means remove first `4` then `3` then `1` and at last `0`, So order should be like this.

```
NSMutableArray *copyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
[copyArray removeObjectAtIndex:4];
[copyArray removeObjectAtIndex:3];
[copyArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];
[copyArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:copyArray animated:false];
```

Comment: Thank you, for your Solution now it is working fine.

Comment: @Gowtham Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray` has a [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1410154-removeobjectsatindexes?language=objc) for this:

```
- (void)removeObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
```

Quoting from the documentation:

> This method is similar to `removeObjectAtIndex:`, but allows you to
>   efficiently remove multiple objects with a single operation.

You could do this (essentially the same as shown in the documentation):

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
[indexes addIndex:1];
[indexes addIndex:3];
[indexes addIndex:4];
[copyArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what exactly you which exactly items you want to show, then it is easier and less error prone to do it like so:

```
NSMutableArray *newItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 3];
newItems.append(self.tabBarController.viewControllers[x1]);
newItems.append(self.tabBarController.viewControllers[x2]);
newItems.append(self.tabBarController.viewControllers[x3]);
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:newItems animated:false];
```